# How to calculate the specifications of the hosting service that I need?

Tags: web-hosting, resources

When shopping for hosting services, each plan has a different specification. This is one example plan:

- 1 Core CPU
- 3 GB RAM
- 300.000 inodes
- 30 Entry Processes
- 30 MB/s I/O
- 5120 IOPS

How do I calculate such plan so that I can buy a suitable one? Say I have a WordPress website that usually have 50 traffics per day, but can get up to 500 per hour. It will install several plugins. Would that be enough?

This answer in the question [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/34726/52079) looks promising, but it doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: installing word-press plugins just for plugins sake is not good. Every plugin you install on your WP site is a possible back-door to your systems and there is really no guarantees that plugins are created with any care.

Comment: do you have any suggestion? If I don't need them, I wouldn't install them at the beginning

Comment: 500 per hour is only one every 7 seconds. You don't need a powerful server to serve 1 request every 7 seconds.

Comment: Is this on a VPS?  Looks like it.  If so, you can generally start small and add more resources as you go.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the simple answer is, without a lot more information specific to your website "You can't"

The specs of that VPS should be more then adequate for your needs, although depending on how many plugins and what you are doing with the site, it may go slow at peak times.

Broadly speaking -

I'd pay particular attention to the number of CPU cores. This is certainly adequate for most sites, but more would be better, and you can't do any real multitasking here.

Likewise, 5120 IOPS/30MB/s is "not great" - especially if you need to worry about backups.  You may want to consider the size of your site (including the database) - if its less then 3 gigs on disk, you will likely find its OK as the OS will cache the reads.

INODES, loosely speaking, is the number of files you can store.  Unless you have a huge number of tiny files, you don't need to worry about this.

The number of entry processes is likely adequate considering its a single CPU.  This is the number of PHP scripts you can run simultaneously.

Comment: What information you need?

Comment: Useful information to help (but not definitively - thete is always an element of "try it and see") answer your question - How large is your site on disk? Do you use a cache plugin? How many plugins do you have? How portant is speed during peek times? When you get 500 "traffics per hour" are most of tjose to a single page?  Is this shared hosting or a VPS?  Is the site currently live, and if so, do you have root access?